# Find a Windows process based on its description, using CMD

Tags: windows, process, cmd

I get two results when I run this:

**tasklist /FI "imagename eq PROCESS.exe"**

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
PROCESS.exe                   2760 Console                    1      8,156 K
PROCESS.exe                  20160 Console                    1      9,060 K
```

But I only want to kill **ONE** of them...

If I open up the Task Manager, I can see that each of my processes have different descriptions.

So all I need to do, is somehow filter by process description.

Can anyone help, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Option flag "/V" might show you differences which can then be used as additional filter properties.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I have tried that sorry, but the description doesn't show up in verbose mode :(

Comment: Look also at [Windows CLI: Show one of two processes with the same name (SuperUser)](http://superuser.com/questions/692823/windows-cli-show-one-of-two-processes-with-the-same-name) if your executable path is different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following to distinguish the processes according to their own process ID and their parent process ID:

```
wmic process get processid,parentprocessid,executablepath | find "PROCESS"
```

This way, you can find the process ID to kill.

`wmic` grants access to additional process properties.

Use `wmic process get /?` to find out what is available.

Another potentially helpful tool is [PsList](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/pslist.aspx) of Microsoft/Sysinternals.

Comment: Would say you could use `Description` column and don't need `executablepath` to obtain it.

Comment: This one worked perfectly. The two processes were running from two different locations, so I could easily get the one I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter your process list by the window title, just use

```
tasklist /FI "windowtitle eq Title"
```

As addition to @Axel's answer with WMI - the same for `description`:

```
WMIC Process WHERE "Description='Only One'" GET ProcessID
```

And in VBS:

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Description = 'My Desc'",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems
'Do Stuff
Next
```

---

Another possible value for *description* is the assembly's description which is retrievable with PowerShell. Use [`Get-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to obtain the assembly path and retrieve its description with `[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo($File).FileDescription`.

Comment: Thank you for all the info!